# Run Python file from CMD with extra things

Tags: python, cmd

I don´t know, how to run a python file (python test.py) with extra stuff, like this:

> python test.py "hello world"
>
> python [FILE]    [SAY]

What i want:

```py
def something(say):
    print(say)
```

Comment: Please refer this link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution (a long time ago btw):

```py
import sys
sys.argv
```

Thats it! It returns a list with all arguments:

> C:\Programs >>> test.py-t "Hello, World!" start
>
> ["test.py","-t","Hello World","start"]

Answer (score 2):

A simple example of using argparse:

```
import argparse

cmd_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
cmd_parser.add_argument('SAY', help= 'The string you want to print on the 
terminal')
args = cmd_parser.parse_args()

print(args.SAY)
```